# Regular expression of two digit number where two digits are not same

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match a two digit number where the two digits are not same.

I have used the following expression:

```
^([0-9])(?!\1)$
```

However, both the strings "11" and "12" are not matching. I thought "12" would match. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `#` is missing in the input - use `$` to denote the end of string and allow 1 more digit.

Comment: `^([0-9])(?!\1)[0-9]$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow matching 2 digits. Your regex `^([0-9])(?!\1)$` only allows 1 digit string. Note that a lookahead *does not consume characters*, it *only checks for presence or absence* of something after the current position.

Use

```
^(\d)(?!\1)\d$
           ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF0hX1/1)

*Explanation of the pattern*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d)` - match and capture into Group #1 a digit
- `(?!\1)` - make sure the next character is not the same digit as in Group 1
- `\d` - one digit
- `$` - end of string.