# Separate a string between each two neighbouring different digits via `re.split` DIRECTLY (in Python)?

Tags: python, regex, split

For instance, I'd like to convert `"91234 5g556７\t7₇89^"` into `["9","1","2","3","4 5g55","6７\t7₇8","9^"]`. Of course this can be done in a for loop without using any regular expressions, but I want to know if this can be done via a singular regular expression. At present I find two ways to do so:

```
>>> import re
>>> def way0(char: str):
...     delimiter = ""
...     while True:
...         delimiter += " "
...         if delimiter not in char:
...             substitution = re.compile("([0-9])(?!\\1)([0-9])")
...             replacement = "\\1"+delimiter+"\\2"
...             cin = [char]
...             while True:
...                 cout = []
...                 for term in cin: cout.extend(substitution.sub(replacement,term).split(delimiter))
...                 if cout == cin:
...                     return cin
...                 else:
...                     cin = cout
...
>>> way0("91234 5g556７\t7₇89^")
['9', '1', '2', '3', '4 5g55', '6７\t7₇8', '9^']
>>> import functools
>>> way1 = lambda w: ["".join(list(y)) for x, y in itertools.groupby(re.split("(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)", w), lambda z: z != "") if x]
>>> way1("91234 5g556７\t7₇89^")
['9', '1', '2', '3', '4 5g55', '6７\t7₇8', '9^']
```

However, neither `way0` nor `way1` is concise (and ideal). I have read the help page of `re.split`; unfortunately, the following code does not return the desired output:

```
>>> re.split(r"(\d)(?!\1)(\d)","91234 5g556７\t7₇89^")
['', '9', '1', '', '2', '3', '4 5g5', '5', '6', '７\t7₇', '8', '9', '^']
```

Can `re.split` solve this problem **directly** (that is, *without extra conversions*)? (Note that here I *don't* focus on the efficiency.)

There are some questions of this topic before (for example, [Regular expression of two digit number where two digits are not same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34219339), [Regex to match 2 digit but different numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51575706), and [Regular expression to match sets of numbers that are not equal nor reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258471)), but they are about "RegMatch". In fact, my question is about "RegSplit" (rather than "RegMatch" or "RegReplace").

Comment: A two step idea: [`re.sub(r"(?<=([0-9]))(?=[0-9])(?!\1)","-",s).split("-")`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWQcnS0MjYRME03dTU7P2e6TEl5o@a2i0s45S4uIpSQQqKUvWKS5M0ipQ07G1sNaINdC1jNTU17G0hLA17xRhDTSUdJV0lnWJNveKCnMwSDSBHk4uroCgzr0QDaIjm//8A)

Comment: If you want to use only split and don't use a capturing group, this would  probably work but I doubt it's more efficient: [`re.split(r"(?=[0-9])(?<=(?!00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)[0-9])", s)`](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DQIhGADQnimQChI13PGfSBjEn44oid4RoDH5KhtHcBmncQFHQI39y8vXdpon0Xu65Lk0XCJCFXtM3DAKidVRKf1@PnbNvG536w4EoRJ/oMR1zefUaCE0@C1fuT2jYeNpWHAOwwDjCEKAlKAUaA3GgLXgHPtTssSVIZRLmr5FrKz3Dw)

Comment: Another possibility: `[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'.*?(?:([0-9])(?=[0-9])(?!\1)|.$)', s)]`

Comment: @bobblebubble Many thanks. The latter way is just what I need. (Surprisingly, when I execute the analogues in another programming language, the "two step idea" is less efficient instead.)

Comment: @Nick Also thanks. It appears that the indirect ``re.finditer`` is more useful than the direct ``re.findall`` here. Right?

Comment: @user688486 it's a little more difficult to use `re.findall` because of the capturing group needed for the negative lookahead, although still doable if you add a second capture group into the regex e.g. `[t[0] for t in re.findall(r'(.*?(?:([0-9])(?=[0-9])(?!\2)|.$))', s)]`

Comment: @user688486 You're welcome! I put this as an answer, glad it helped. :) Also Nick's idea looks very nice, mabye you get more answers.

Comment: @Nick This way is really amazing. I never knew these before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve this using `re.split` without capturing and any further processing in one step, an idea is to use only [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and in the look*behind* disallow two same digits looking *ahead*.

```
(?=[0-9])(?<=(?!00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)[0-9])
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FEyhAG/1) or [the Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DQIhGADQnimQChI13PGfSBjEn44oid4RoDH5KhtHcBmncQFHQI39y8vXdpon0Xu65Lk0XCJCFXtM3DAKidVRKf1@PnbNvG536w4EoRJ/oMR1zefUaCE0@C1fuT2jYeNpWHAOwwDjCEKAlKAUaA3GgLXgHPtTssSVIZRLmr5FrKz3Dw)

The way it works is obvious. The lookarounds find any position between two digits. Inside the look*behind* the negative look*ahead* prevents matching (before) if two same digits are ahead.

I used `[0-9]` and not `\d` because unsure [if `\d` matches unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/5527985) in your Python version.

Comment: Thank you. Using `\d` with `flags=re.A` also works, but this only leads to more keystrokes in fact. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), although it is a little more complicated with `findall` due to the capture group required for a negative lookahead (since `findall` returns the contents of capture groups in its result).

```py
s ="91234 5g556７\t7₇89^"

# re.finditer
[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'.*?(?:([0-9])(?=[0-9])(?!\1)|.$)', s)]

# re.findall
[t[0] for t in re.findall(r'(.*?(?:([0-9])(?=[0-9])(?!\2)|.$))', s)]
```

In both cases the answer is

```
['9', '1', '2', '3', '4 5g55', '6７\t7₇8', '9^']
```

Python demo at [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWydLQyNhEwTTd1NTs/Z7pMSXmj5raLSzjlLi4lIFq9NIy81IyS1KLuIpSgaoVonP10ovySws0DDQV0vKLFHIVMvOQlWkUqetp2WvYW2lEG@haxmpq2NvCGIoxhpo1eiqa6joKxZqxXAVFmXklGkBTNZFsSszJgVlUEm0QC7aiBMkKoDzQBg3cVhiBrcC04/9/AA)